# How to make the quartz scheduler job to standby when using quartz 3.x version in dotnet core 3.1 or 6

Tags: .net-core, quartz.net

I have implemented the quartz scheduler using 3.4 version and dotnet core 3.1 using below code, now i want to pause or standby the triggers or jobs.

```
services.AddTransient<someJob>();
services.AddSingleton<ITypeLoadHelper, SimpleTypeLoadHelper>();

var jobKey = new JobKey("SomeJob");
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
   q.SchedulerId = "JobScheduler";
   q.SchedulerName = "Job Scheduler";
   q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();
   q.AddJob<SomeJob>(j => j.WithIdentity(jobKey));
   q.AddTrigger(t => t
      .WithIdentity("someJobTrigger")
      .ForJob(jobKey)
      .StartNow()
      .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(14, 00))
   );
});

services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
{
   options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

the thing is how can i get the scheduler object here?

tried below - it doesn't makes it to standby - i think its creating new object instead of getting the default scheduler created in above code.

```
var scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
await scheduler.Standby();
await scheduler.PauseTrigger(new TriggerKey(workerTriggerKeyName));
```

Edit: Tried to change as per suggestion from @lahma

```
        services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory>(con => GetSchedulerFactory());
        services.AddSingleton<IScheduler>(con => GetScheduler());



private static IScheduler GetScheduler()
{
    if (scheduler == null)
    {
        // Create a Quartz.NET scheduler
        scheduler = GetSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler().Result;
    }
    return scheduler;
}

private static ISchedulerFactory GetSchedulerFactory()
{
    if (schedulerFactory == null)
    {
        // Create a Quartz.NET scheduler
        schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        //scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
    }
    return schedulerFactory;
}
```

but after this the worker is not running at all.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posting is pretty lame, you should always inform about it:  https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/1722

Answer (score 0):

i have used the program.cs code as it is:

```
services.AddTransient<someJob>();
services.AddSingleton<ITypeLoadHelper, SimpleTypeLoadHelper>();

var jobKey = new JobKey("SomeJob");
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
   q.SchedulerId = "JobScheduler";
   q.SchedulerName = "Job Scheduler";
   q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();
   q.AddJob<SomeJob>(j => j.WithIdentity(jobKey));
   q.AddTrigger(t => t
      .WithIdentity("someJobTrigger")
      .ForJob(jobKey)
      .StartNow()
      .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(14, 00))
   );
});

services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
{
   options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

And inside the worker job i used following property *context.Scheduler* to get the scheduler

```
public class WorkerJob : IJob
{       
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      await context.Scheduler.PauseTrigger(triggerName);
      await context.Scheduler.ResumeTrigger(triggerName);
    }
}
```